# WP All Import IF Statement

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I'm using WPAI to import some info into WooCommerce Product Description.
What i want to do is look at the dimensions size and only place it in the description if the field contains data and ignore if it is empty.

So i attempted this code on a field that has a value but nothing shows

```
[IF({assembledwidthmm1[1][.=""]})][ELSE]{assembledwidthmm1[1]}[ENDIF]
```

Additionally if i could get this to work i would also like to display some text within this, only if the field contains data.

For example

```
[IF({assembledwidthmm1[1][.=""]})][ELSE] Width :{assembledwidthmm1[1]} mm [ENDIF]
```

Any direction on this would be amazing .. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of markup is that? Some template engine?

Comment: Yes it's specific to WP All Import .. so for me to place assembled width from a CSV import into a WooCommerce description i would place this {assembledwidthmm1[1]}

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I'm trying to do the exact same thing

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
[IF({assembledwidthmm1[1][.=""]})][ELSE] Width :{assembledwidthmm1[1]} mm [ENDIF]
```

Is working fine in my tests. Since it's not working for you, try using a custom PHP function instead: http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/execute-php/. Example function:

```
function my_display_width( $width = '' ) {
    return empty( $width ) ? null : 'Width: ' . $width . 'mm';  
}
```

You'd use this in the import template like so:

```
[my_display_width({assembledwidthmm1[1]})]
```

In general it's best to use PHP functions for things like this since the syntax is easier to understand and it's more flexible.

Comment: Your first line also works great for me, but what I am trying to do now is flip it around.

So in your example you are returning nothing if the field is blank in the CSV, I want to do something like:

IF Assembled Width = "A Value", then "Specific Text", ELSE "".

So I tried this but it didn't work.
[IF({producttype[1][="R1"]})R1 Text][ELSE]Not R1[ENDIF]

Can you see what I've done wrong?